# How to combine CSV data into multiple new CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a directory of about 5000 CSV files listed as an item name i.e. tuna.csv (df/tuna.csv). All file names are different in this directory

Each CSV file has a DATE column and a PRICE column as so:

```
DATE        PRICE
2010-01-01   1.00
2010-01-02   1.10
...
2019-06-12   1.45
```

I would like to pair each CSV file with each other and create a new CSV file with the price ratio of the two i.e. tuna/salmon in a different directory (ratios/tuna_salmon.csv).

There are far too many CSV files to do this manually, would there be a way to loop this process? Reciprocals are fine. Just not sure how to reference/enumerate this for automation as there is no uniformity in the CSV file names.

I do have a list of the 5000+ in my py file:
ITEMS = [tuna, ..., salmon]

Any information on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use pandas https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can scan all the directory and memorized the name of the files in a list. After you have to loop over the list, open the first file and so on and compare to all the other file in the list. You can read 2 file sequentially in python with zip or: width open() as f1, open() as f2:

Sorry for the fast reply but im on smartphone